# Changing content of tables dynamically in php

Tags: php, jquery, html, dynamic

Currently i have pages where HTML tables are filled by data taken from php. Now im trying to make this dynamic, that is changing the data in HTML tables on same page. I need to know how can i change the PHP code dynamically. Im using Jquery for changing content dynamically but i am not able to change the php code accordingly. any suggestions on how i might achieve this?

Comment: Have a look at `jQuery.post()` (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and maybe Ajax in general.

Comment: You cann't change PHP CODE DYNAMICALLY.you can change parameters/values that are sent to php code Dynamically. Using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

you probably want something like this:

```
<?php
echo "<table>";
foreach($rows as $cols)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($cols as $col)
    {
        echo "<td>".$col."</td>;
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable) attribute, supported in almost [every browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable).

### HTML

```
<table>
  ...
  <td>
    <div tabindex="0" contenteditable="true">Cell content</div>
  </td>
</table>
```

### JavaScript

```
$('[contenteditable="true"]').on(
  'blur', // this action will trigger when the user blur the editable area,
          // you can also listen to a form submit.
  function(event) {
    $.post('tableController.php', {
      content: $(event.target).text()
    })
      .done(function(response) {
        alert(response);
      });
  }
);
```